# JPA multiple search in two fields by string

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have input string, like that "part of name and part of surName" 
And in my entity I have two fields: name and surName. 
And i want fold this two fields name + " " + surName and then search my text "part of name and part of surName" in this new String from two fields. 
Can I create this query in JPA? Or i must choose separately this fields and then already on Java BE, fold them and start search by string also on BE?

Comment: hibernate with solr gives excellent search features. Have a look at my demo here https://code.google.com/p/hb-search-demo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select p from Person p 
where concat(p.name, ' ', p.surname) like concat('%', :part, '%')
```